# Passar parametros no redirect do express + node + ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs

Ola, estou querendo passar parametros no redirect da mesma maneira que faço no metodo render, preciso que seja redirect pois não quero renderizar uma pagina e sim redirecionar para a rota da API que ja esta renderizando a pagina com os dados que preciso.

Tem como eu passar um parametro no res.redirect para depois verificar no front-end se ele existe e printar a mensagem em que eu passar como parametro a ideia seria similar o que esta abaixo tem alguma maneira de se fazer isto.

```
Aluno.findAndCount({ where: { AL_TURMA: id } }).then((alunos) => {

            if (alunos.count === 0) {
                Turma.destroy({ where: { TR_ID: id } })
                res.status(200).redirect('/turmas', /*msg: sucesso*/);
            } else {
                res.status(200).redirect('/turmas', /*{ msg: 'Existem alunos nesta turma. Não é possivel excluir' }*/)
            }
        })
```

Existem alguma forma de fazer isto ?

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar uma API chamada **[connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash)** que permite armazenar mensagem que deverao ser informadas ao usuario. Quando houver um erro, voce informa ao flash e redireciona para determinada rota e apos a informacao ser renderizada e sera apagada automaticamente do objeto flash. Vou lhe mostrar um exemplo que voce pode aplicar no seu projeto.

```
  //Apos instalar como dependencia no seu projeto, faca:
  const flash = require("connect-flash");
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();

  // ...

  app.use(flash()); // aplicando o connect-flash na sua aplicacao.


  // *********** Exemplo no controller ******************
  // neste exemplo, vamos supor que tenho um controller que faz um cadastro de cliente. 
  // se houver algum erro na hora de criar cadastro e eu quiser redirecionar para esta rota, 
  // o req.flash("error") sera substituido pelo valor definido no metodo que redirecionou.

  // controller para a rota '/cadastro'
  exports.cadastrar = (req, res) => {
    res.render("view/cadastro", {
     error: req.flash("error"), 
   });
  };

  // controller para a rota 'post/cadastrar'
  exports.postCriarCadastro = (req, res) => {
    // ...
    if (error === true) {
     // se houve um erro, defino uma uma mensagem para o flash para ser exibido no redirecionamento.
     // informamos ao req.flash('variavel', 'mensagem de erro').
     req.flash("error", "Email ja em uso. Tente outro endereco de email!");
     res.redirect("/cadastro"); // vou redirecionar para a rota de cadastro
    }
  };
```